# How to pass response paramaters including body from POST http.request in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

I am trying to write a basic REST Post client to work with node.js and because of the REST API I have to work with I have to get details from the responses including cookies to maintain the state of my REST session with the server. My Question is what is the best way to pull the json objects from the response when res.on triggers with all the data in the PRINTME variable and return it to the test.js console.log().

### test.js file

```
var rest = require('./rest');
rest.request('http','google.com','/upload','data\n');
console.log('PRINTME='JSON.stringify(res.PRINTME));
```

### rest.js module

```
exports.request = function (protocol, host, path, data, cookie){
var protocalTypes = {
    http: {
        module: require('http')
        , port: '80'
    }
    , https: {
        module: require('https')
        , port: '443'
    }
};

var protocolModule = protocalTypes[protocol].module;

var options = {
    host: host,
    port: protocalTypes[protocol].port,
    path: path,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/xml'
        , 'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(data)
        , 'Cookie': cookie||''
    }
};

console.log('cookies sent= '+options.headers.Cookie)

var req = protocolModule.request(options, function(res) {
    var PRINTME = res;
    console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
    console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        PRINTME.body = chunk;
        console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
    });
    res.on('close', function () {res.emit('end')});
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.error('Request Failure: ' + e.message);
 });

req.write(data);
req.end();
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a package like [request](http://github.com/mikeal/request) will help you simplify your code.

The following would be `rest.js`
    var request = require('request');

```
module.exports = function(protocol, host, path, data, cookie, done) { 

    var options = {
        host: host,
        port: protocalTypes[protocol].port,
        path: path,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'text/xml',
            'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(data)
        },
        jar: true
    };

  request(options, function(err, resp, body) {
    if (err) return done(err);

    // call done, with first value being null to specify no errors occured
    return done(null, resp, body);
  });
}
```

Setting `jar` to `true` will remember cookies for future use.

See this link for more information on the available options

https://github.com/mikeal/request#requestoptions-callback

To use this function in another file

```
var rest = require('./rest');

rest(... , function(err, resp, body){
   ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it still doesn't answer the question about how to get the value from inside a call back function like that back to the main program. 

As I side note thanks to your suggestion I am trying 'request' but I am still having massive issues with what seems like getting the cookies to persist between request calls.

Comment: To get the value back out into your main app (or the caller) use a callback to the function being exported in `rest.js`. I've updated my answer above.

Comment: Thanks @Bulkan for the response that makes it much clearer. I figured out how to monitor the cookies using a cookieJar variable and found that the calls aren't being made asynchronously. Trying to use async to get them to run in line. Thanks for your help not sure if you can help me with any additional insight on how to get them to run asynchronously.

Comment: I was able to figure out how to use the callback function to trigger the next call. I am good thanks for your help.